# how to setup mkmapview to display pois at 100 meters range from my current location?

Tags: location, mkmapview, point-of-interest

i have 200 pois in my app. i want to display the nearest pois to the user within 100 meters range in a mapview. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the collection of annotations, and use the distanceFromLocation method of CLLocation to establish how far they are from the device position. If they are within range simply add them.